# Linq to EF Dynamic Search with multiple properties

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, search

Given the follwing:

SQL Tables:

```
Names
-----
Id (int)
FirstName (varchar)
LastName (varchar)

NameProperties
----------
Id (int)
NameId (int) FK to Names Id
PropType (int)
PropValue (int)
```

Every Name can have multiple NameProperties

Now my searchCriteria Class is as follows

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public List<KeyValuePair<int,int>> Properties { get; set; } Corresponding to a list of PropType ProValue
```

How do I search using linq to EF when having multiple PropType & PropValues ?

Comment: ok...can you add more detail as to what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @NiK I'm trying to search through names given a certain firstname and lastname a list of PropType & PropValue

Comment: Is the `Any` extension not working for you? Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the criteria in `Properties` should all be met (i.e. `AND` and not `OR`) you could do this:

```
// c is a searchCriteria object.
var query = context.Names
    .Where(n => n.FirstName == c.FirstName && n.LastName == c.LastName);
foreach(var pair in c.Properties)
{
    query = query.Where(n => n.NameProperties.Any(np => 
        np.PropType == pair.PropType && np.PropValue == pair.PropValue;
}
```

(not checked for syntax, just showing the idea).

It is not very efficient to query this way, but querying an [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) is always a pain. If it is even remotely possible to change the Name table in a way that it includes columns corresponding with the NameProperties then do it.

Comment: I see you un-accepted this. OK with me, but is there anything I can improve?

Comment: I re-accepted it, I have done it by mistake ! I'm currently re-testing something and I'll give you my feedback again! Thanks

Comment: Okay there's a problem with this, if Names has multiple properties It's returning the same n result by the number n properties it has

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird, it should translate to `EXISTS`s, so results should not be multiplied (as `JOIN` would do). Can you verify this?